# Following an update of Hombrew, the reinstallation of postgresql, I can no longer create a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I updated the Homebrew version and uninstalled and reinstalled postgresql because I had the following problem after the Homebrew update.
[image]

Now when I try to create a database I get this error.
Does someone have an idea?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: if you have error logs, don't screenshot them but provide the text.

Comment: did you have a a look at `brew services` to see if homebrew did start the database or `brew services restart postgresql`?